# Method called if UIBarButtonItem:initWithImage: is used but not UIBarButtonItem:initWithCustomView:

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a method that I want to get called when the user clicks on a button in the navigation bar. If I add the button like this then my method gets called:

```
  UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myEditButton"]
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                  target:self 
                                                                  action: @selector(enterEditMode:)];
  editButton.title = @"Edit";
  [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:editButton animated:YES];
```

When the user clicks on the button then my enterEditMode: method gets called.

However using this code the result looks like as in the attachment - there's no text but worse my image is lying on top of a blue button. I can't use the standard system edit button because there is a requirement for it to be colored black not blue and AFAIA I'm unable to change the color of the standard edit bar button to black?

So in a xib I created a parent UIView which contains a UIImageView which is the button image and a UILabel for the text.
Then I create the button item like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.editButtonParentView];
[editButton setTarget:self];
[editButton setAction: @selector(enterEditMode:)];
editButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
editButton.target = self;
self.editButtonLabel.text = @"Edit"
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:editButton animated:YES];
```

Where editButtonParentView is an IBOutlet to the partent view in the nib.

This displays perfectly, however the problem is that enterEditMode: does not get called when the user clicks on it.

Why does it not get called?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: regarding editButtonParentView, perhaps make sure that this View does NOT have UserInteractionEnabled?  You want to ensure that the UIBarButtonItem responds to events.  This is just a guess

Comment: That doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/03/31/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem/) is where I found out how you can get the same look as the system 'Edit' button but get any background color you want. Try this code:

// From:

```
#import "UIBarButtomItem+Tinted.h"

@implementation UIBarButtonItem (Tinted)

+ (UIBarButtonItem *)newBarButtonItemWithTint:(UIColor*)color andTitle:(NSString*)itemTitle andTarget:(id)theTarget andSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    UISegmentedControl *button      = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[itemTitle]];
    button.momentary                = YES;
    button.segmentedControlStyle    = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    button.tintColor                = color;

    [button addTarget:theTarget action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do the trick. However I am very curious still to know why my method is not getting called in my original code.

Comment: You will have to ask Apple! I replicated what you had - I could not get the action message either. What I've seen before is similar to the code above - you can add a button as a customView, then set the button's target/selector as I did to get the barButton to respond. I don't know how to do it with a vanilla view.